# Can I keep my job as a foreign contractor for a U.S. company, while I am in the U.S. working as a temporary unpaid volunteer?

Tags: usa, working-visas, eu-citizens, j-visa, foreign-employment

I am an EU citizen and I work for a U.S.-based company as a foreign contractor.

I am planning to go to the U.S. for a six-month project as a Visiting Scholar in a University. I would be on a J-Researcher visa and I would work there as an unpaid volunteer. This visa (as far as I understand) allows me to work only in that specific University program.

Can I keep my foreign contractor job with the other U.S. company, even if I am physically in the U.S. in that period without a U.S. work visa? My taxes would still be paid in my home country.